# xslt how to generate sequence of untyped atomic?

Tags: xslt

I have a loop like so in a template:

```
    <xsl:variable name="seq">
        <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="2"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="3"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="4"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="5"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="$seq">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to iterate once over each element of $seq, producing:
(1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
(5)

Instead this code produces (1 2 3 4 5)

How can I create a proper sequence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
<xsl:variable name="seq" select="1,2,3,4,5"/>

<xsl:value-of select="for $i in $seq return concat('(', $i, ')')" separator=" "/>
```

should do. Or what do you want to achieve? For your approach doing

```
<xsl:variable name="seq" as="item()*">
        <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="2"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="3"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="4"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="5"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

might improve things but looks rather complicated if all you want is a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A variable with contained instructions and no as attribute, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="seq">
    <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="2"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="3"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="4"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="5"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

represents a document node, in this case a document node containing a single text node whose string content is "1 2 3 4 5". If you want a sequence of five integers, either use the select attribute, or write

```
<xsl:variable name="seq" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="2"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="3"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="4"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="5"/>
</xsl:variable>
```